# Populate field in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using below aggregation query to get data from two collections:

```
let condition = {assignId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)};
Project.aggregate([
    {
      $match: condition  
    },
    {
      "$group":{
        "_id": "$_id"
      }
    },
    { 
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "worksheets",
        "let": { "projectId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$projectId", "$$projectId" ] }}},
          { "$group": {_id:"$projectId", totalHours:{"$sum": "$hours"}}}
        ],
        "as": "project"
      }
    }
])
.then((data)=>{
    res.json(data);
})
```

and getting the below result:

```
[
 {
    "_id": "5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024",
    "project": [
        {
            "_id": "5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024",
            "totalHours": 10
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "_id": "5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac",
    "project": [
        {
            "_id": "5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac",
            "totalHours": 6
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

I want to populate the _id field inside the project Array. What changes should i need to do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
Project.aggregate([
  { "$match": condition },
  { "$group":{ "_id": "$_id" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "worksheets",
    "let": { "projectId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$projectId", "$$projectId" ] }}},
      { "$group": {_id:"$projectId", totalHours:{"$sum": "$hours"}}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "projects",
        "let": { "projectId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$projectId" ] }}},
          { "$project": { "projectName": 1 }}
        ],
        "as": "project"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "worksheet"
  }}
])
```

Comment: what about, if i want to get specific fields?

Comment: Use the `$project` stage and specify the fields you want. As I did above inside the second `$lookup`. `{ "$project": { "projectName": 1 }}`

Comment: I have a developers array inside the project field. I want to populate it also.

Comment: Use one more `$lookup` inside that `pipeline`.

Comment: I did below and getting the developers array = [] and _id = null.

Comment: {
                "$group":{
                  "_id": "$developers",
                }
              },
              { 
                "$lookup": {
                  "from": "users",
                  "let": { "developers": "$_id" },
                  "pipeline": [
                    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$developers" ] }}},
                  ],
                  "as": "developers"
                }
              }

Comment: Can you please answer of my above comment?

Comment: @test Please wait

Comment: I tried it, But it is array, so giving me _id:null and developers:[]. So how to solve it, please?

Comment: please share any reference with me. if you don't have time as this issues are urgent for me.

Comment: I am not getting it. It is the last query for today. Please do it for me.

Comment: Ok please ask a new question for that.

Comment: sure, give me 5 minutes, I am sharing a new url with you. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the url : 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722295/populate-to-the-deep-level-using-lookup-mongodb'